# WebFlux RestController parameter handling

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm using WebFlux to create a REST controller. My question is, how do I handle request parameters/request body? Can I pass them like the old way and remain reactive?

```
@PostMapping("/register")
Mono<User> register(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
    return userService.registerUser(userRegistrationDto);
}
```

Or do I need to read the `UserRegistrationDto` from `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest` and do the validation manually? Maybe my method should accept `Mono<UserRegistrationDto>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice, if you prefer the 'old' way of `RestControllers` then the way you posted is just fine. If you prefer the new way of `handlers` and `routes` then you would need a serverRequest.bodyToMono as you stated.